# Why is my code not finding my navigation partial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have the following file:

contact.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: skyblue;
            font-family: verdana,serif;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 48px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<% include('partials/nav'); %>

<h1>Contact Us</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('partials/index');
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.render('partials/contact');
});

app.get('/profile/:name', function (req, res) {
    var data = {age: 30, job: 'ninja', hobbies: ['eating', 'hunting', 'fishing']};
    res.render('profile', {person: req.params.name, data: data});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And the following nav.ejs file:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With the following file structure:
[image]

When I run the code using:

> nodemon app.js

I receive the following error in my browser and in my WebStorm IDE:

```
 Error: /home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/views/partials/contact.ejs:29
    27| </head>
    28| <body>
 >> 29| <% include('partials/nav'); %>
    30| 
    31| <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    32| </body>

Could not find the include file "partials/nav"
    at getIncludePath (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:165:13)
    at includeFile (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:291:19)
    at include (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:654:16)
    at eval (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/views/partials/contact.ejs:12:8)
    at contact (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:656:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/doug/WebstormProjects/node-js-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

It is stating that it could not find the file but it appears to be structured right for me. This has been driving me nuts so posting. If there is anything I can add for clarity, please let me know.

What is wrong with my code that is preventing it from displaying the navigation file?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: i think you need to put a slash / before partials

Comment: Try `/partials/nav` or `./partials/nav`

Comment: @AhmedSunny It is now return the following error: " >> 29| <% include('/partials/nav'); %>"

Comment: @AhmedSunny After changing, I receive the following error:  >> 29| <% include('/partials/nav'); %>

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the problem by switching

```
<% include('partials/nav'); %>
```

to

```
<%- include('nav'); %>
```